# Python interactive mode does not work in my anaconda3 environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

Once I try to run python on my conda environment it blcok like this and nothing change:

```
(python3) user todoapp
$ python
```

Knowing that python was intalled in my conda env using `conda create -n python3 python=3` and I have runned my env using `source activate python3`. What suprising me is once I run `ipython`this work normally but `python` no :(.

I have searched in the net but nothing solved my issue. Is theire any option?

Answer (score -1):

You're naming your virtual environment `python3`?? That's the same alias for actual Python 3 binary file in many operating systems, don't do that.
Create another virtual environment with another name (or clone that env to another name) and move your project files to it. Then [remove](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment) your `python3` env.
See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html on the related commands and paths.

Comment: It is mentioned as good practice in one cource that is why I used it. I will try what you said and see if this can fix my error.

Comment: Still does not fix the pb. whatever the name I chose to create the env it does not work the interactive mode of python.

Comment: did you clean up the `python3` folders? like the folder in which your project used to be

Comment: You mean remove it?

Comment: renaming it should be fine as well. I'm thinking removing every possibility of confusion between `python3` as calling python3 binary with anything, then if that's not what caused the problme, without it should be easier to weed out to the source of the problem

Comment: Ok I will do an we will see thought I do not think this was the problem. Coz I have seen a demo using same name and their is no issue.

Comment: I did clear it up still not fixing the problem. I have told you that the appelation has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: lets continue this to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: Naming an env `python3` is fine (though naming after the project it is for might be a better practice). Env names are typically only passed as arguments to the `conda activate` or as a `--name|-n` value; it's not going to get mixed up with a binary. Something else must be the issue.

Comment: @merv it's not a good practice or idea. read conda's doc about what happened when you create a virtual env, it's _creating a folder_ named as python3. That's not the same as 'only as argument', or creating a metadata entry in a config file. By default that folder's in the `<conda>/envs` directory but it can be [in the project folder](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment), in which case now `python3` is ambiguous, invoking interpreter or specifying a folder name.